# Transfer data from DynamoDB to SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, etl

I want to transfer data from amazon dynamo DB to SQL server 2008. What are the tools or methods which can be used to do this ?

Comment: How big is the data? I do not know dynamoDB, but this can have an impact on the proposed solution.